# Rock paper scissors game, infinite loop

Tags: python

```
import random

options = ['Rock','Paper', 'Scissor']
npc = random.choice(options)

print('Hello')
print('We are about to play Rock,Paper,Scissors.')

while True:
  npc = random.choice(options)
  player = str(input('Please declare your weapon: ')).capitalize()
  if (player == npc):
    print('Your choice: ', player)
    print('npc choice: ', npc)
    print('Oopsie looks like we have a tie!')
    print('Lets Try again!')
    continue
  if (player != 'Rock') or (player != 'Paper') or (player != 'Scissor'):
    print('Poo Poo, that is not a valid option! Please try again!')
    continue
  if ((player == 'Rock') and (npc == 'Scissor')) or ((player == 'Scissor') and (npc == 'Paper')) or ((player == 'Paper') and (npc == 'Rock')):
    print('Your choice: ', player)
    print('npc choice: ', npc)
    print('You win!')
    break
  if ((player == 'Rock') and (npc == 'Paper')) or ((player == 'Scissor') and (npc == 'Rock')) or ((player == 'Paper') and (npc == 'Scissor')):
    print('Your choice: ', player)
    print('npc choice: ', npc)
    print('You lose!')
    break
```

It keeps printing out it's a Tie and won't display any other results. I'm just starting out in programming. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

edit: the loop has been solved.

this is the sample output as per request:

```
   Output: Hello
           We are about to play Rock,Paper,Scissors.
           Please declare your weapon: rock
           Your choice:  Rock
           npc choice:  Paper
           You lose!
```

Comment: @dstrants ya I'm getting them, Lutz's solution solved the loop problem!

Comment: Can you also post the output of the script?

Comment: @dstrants I've posted it.

Comment: @dstrants The output will depend on the input and the result of `random.choice`. It is very easy to spot the error in this code by just reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if (player != 'Rock') or (player != 'Paper') or (player != 'Scissor'):
```

will always be `True` if there is no tie. Change it to

```
if player not in options:
```

**Some suggestions to improve your code**

You can remove the `()`s in all your `if`s. This

```
if (player == npc):
```

is the same as

```
if player == npc:
```

You should also use `if/elif/else` instead of only `if`. This will make the use of `continue` unncessary.

**Edit:** Improved version:

```
import random

options = ['Rock','Paper', 'Scissor']
npc = random.choice(options)

print('Hello')
print('We are about to play Rock,Paper,Scissors.')

while True:
  npc = random.choice(options)
  player = str(input('Please declare your weapon: ')).capitalize()
  if player == npc:
    print('Your choice: ', player)
    print('npc choice: ', npc)
    print('Oopsie looks like we have a tie!')
    print('Lets Try again!')
  elif player not in options:
    print('Poo Poo, that is not a valid option! Please try again!')
  elif (player == 'Rock' and npc == 'Scissor') or (player == 'Scissor' and npc == 'Paper') or (player == 'Paper' and npc == 'Rock'):
    print('Your choice: ', player)
    print('npc choice: ', npc)
    print('You win!')
    break
  else:
    print('Your choice: ', player)
    print('npc choice: ', npc)
    print('You lose!')
    break
```

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical error in your program.

Specifically this line:

```
if (player != 'Rock') or (player != 'Paper') or (player != 'Scissor'):
```

The 'or' operator returns True if at least one of the statements it links is True.

For example, say the player chose 'Rock'. Now the first statement `player != 'Rock'` is False but the second one `player != 'Paper'` is True, and so is `player != 'Scissor'`.

So, the overall statement becomes `False or True or True` which is True and the program ends up telling the user that their choice is not valid.

You can fix this easily by using 'and' instead of 'or' like so:

```
if (player != 'Rock') and (player != 'Paper') and (player != 'Scissor'):
```

Here, the statement becomes `False and True and True` which is False. This statement returns True only if the player entered a choice that is not one of the options: `Rock, Paper, Scissor`, as intended.

A more Pythonic way of doing this would be to replace the whole statement with the following, as mentioned in the other answer:

```
if player not in options:
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make some improvements like use `if-elif`, instead of `continue`. Also use `.format(...)` for representation of reply.

And for your loop problem, change the logic operator in the second if statement to `and` operator for inclusive iteration.

The final formatted code looks like this:

```
import random

options = ['Rock','Paper', 'Scissor']
npc = random.choice(options)

print('Hello')
print('We are about to play Rock,Paper,Scissors.')

while True:
    npc = random.choice(options)
    player = str(input('Please declare your weapon: ')).capitalize()
    if (player == npc):
        print('Your choice: {}'.format(player))
        print('npc choice: {}'.format(npc))
        print('Oopsie looks like we have a tie!')
        print('Lets Try again!')
    elif (player != 'Rock') and (player != 'Paper') and (player != 'Scissor'):
        print('Poo Poo, that is not a valid option! Please try again!')
    elif ((player == 'Rock') and (npc == 'Scissor')) or ((player == 'Scissor') and (npc == 'Paper')) or ((player == 'Paper') and (npc == 'Rock')):
        print('Your choice: {}'.format(player))
        print('npc choice: {}'.format(npc))
        print('You win!')
        break
    elif ((player == 'Rock') and (npc == 'Paper')) or ((player == 'Scissor') and (npc == 'Rock')) or ((player == 'Paper') and (npc == 'Scissor')):
        print('Your choice: {}'.format(player))
        print('npc choice: {}'.format(npc))
        print('You lose!')
        break
```

Comment: Is having multiple if statements bad practice? or are elif statements better in some way?